# Does calling functions inside others cause performance issues?

Tags: python

This question isn't really Python-specific, but it is the first time I have ever come across it.

Simply, I have some functions which are called by my `main`, but I need my `main` function to be called every time one of them ends. Here's some code demonstrating the issue:

```
def main():
    text = raw_input()
    command(text)

def command(name):
    if name == "help":
        helpcmd()
    else:
        main()

def helpCmd():
    print("This is the help command")
    main()

main()
```

I fear that after a while my process will look like:

`main->command->helpCmd->main->command->main->...`

Will this be a performance problem? If so, any advice on what to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP thinks it should be deleted and IMHO it has little value for the community.

Comment: I don't think it should be deleted, I only think it's not necessary to keep it from being here since some newcomers can have the same interrogation as me... That's not an useful question or answer, but it's not completely useless either, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, you need to understand the call stack.

Any time a function is called, the program needs to remember where it was so that -- when the callee returns -- it can jump back to the same point in the caller. Therefore, it pushes its current state onto a stack. Using functions is a big part of best practice (for so many reasons: abstraction, encapsulation, code reuse, etc.), so modern languages (including Python) make pushing a frame onto the stack a very lightweight operation. However, it is not **free**.

If you use a function that calls itself as a loop, you will eventually overflow the call stack. The best thing to do if you need a program to loop indefinitely (or even a large number of times) is to use the construct made for that purpose: a loop.

**Note:** See chepner's comment about tail-call optimization, which is a part of the compilation/execution process in many languages (especially functional languages).

Comment: Thank you a lot! That actually is exactly what I would have wanted if only I hadn't solved my own issue before posting it.
I really appreciate the fact that you gave a precise answer anyways, as that gave me the knowledge of the issue regardless of the fact that I had the solution. Thank you!

Comment: I'll mark this one as accepted, because it actually answers the point of my question: performance with repeatedly called function in Python. Thank you again!

Comment: Note that this practice is fine in languages with tail-call optimization. For instance, `main` does nothing but return itself once `command` returns, so `command` could reuse `main`'s stack frame instead of getting its own. (Python does not mandate TCO because the full stack is considered a vital part of debugging.)

Answer (score 1):

Eh... This was actually not an issue at all, as that was just me thinking in weird ways.

To put it simply, every time I called the `main` function should be replaced with a simple `return` instruction, in order to leave the function and just get back to the parent function itself. Now, that also wouldn't work without adding a call to the `main` function inside an endless loop, such as:

```
while True:
    main()
```

Now that would force the process to wait for the end of every `main()` cycle to start a new one, instead of just stupidly calling itself back every time it reaches the end.

Comment: it's also possible to delete your question & answer...

Comment: I figured that would not necessarily be the best solution, since I wondered that myself and didn't find an answer online for it (figures...). Now, if anybody has the same brain failure as me, that maybe will save them some searching for themselves.

Comment: @Rinyuaru-Kun what they would find would be a question and answer that keeps emphasising how "stupid" the mistake they have is in the first place. Littering your posts in self-deprecation is not a useful way of communicating a process.

Comment: @roganjosh You're right, editing that right away